# Taking quotients is left exact

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

(Assuming rings to be commutative with unity.) Given a local ring $(A,m_A)$, I want to know if given an injective map of $A$-modules $M\rightarrow N$, is the $A/m_A$-module map $M/m_AM \rightarrow N/m_AN$ injective.

I am confused because I know that taking quotients isn't left exact in general. But, I haven't been able to find a counterexample. In fact, assuming that $A$ is a discrete valuation ring, I have actually been able to apply structure theorem to convince myself that the injectivity is preserved.

Anyone got a hint?

Comment: Do you want to consider your $A$-modules as $A/m_A$-modules? I'm confused what you mean exactly by "taking quotients" here.

Comment: I've clarified.

Comment: Since $M/m_A M\cong M\otimes_A A/m_A$, you are actually asking whether $A/m_A$ is a flat $A$-module as far as I can tell.

Comment: Okay, I got it now! I never thought of it this way, the counterexample is easy now. Thanks!